# Rails before_update not triggering

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a very simple rails model and i am trying to change the values before the update:

```
before_update { self.notes = "from the model" }
```

but this update doesn't work, what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: does the record validate and save, just the callback not getting called.

Comment: @Doon - yes the record validates and saves

Comment: and the other question, This is an existing record you are updating, not a new record you are creating/saving?

Comment: @Doon - updating an existing record, yes

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
before_update 'self.notes = "from the model"'
```

Or

```
before_update { |record| record.notes = "from the model" }
```

Or

```
before_update :change_notes

private
def change_notes
  self.notes = "from the model"
end
```

Make sure you are not updating your `self.notes` after `before_update` callback, otherwise you will not see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
before_save :change_notes

private
def change_notes
  self.notes = "from the model"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use a proc. I generally tend to use this pattern:

```
set_callback :update, :before do |model|
  model.notes = "from the model"
end
```

Doing it this way allows you to explicitly specify the instance of the model that you want to change (i.e. in this case "model"). The callback will automatically pass model instance to the Proc at run time.

However, just a quick note - if you have a model class named "Model", with an instance named "my_model", be sure that what you're trying to modify (i.e. "notes") is actually part of the instance and not the class. If it is instead part of the class, it will at best error out, telling you right away that something is wrong, or at worst set a class variable that all instances will share leading to non-deterministic results.

Comment: Btw - I realise this is a bit late, but thought to add my 2 cents :-)